# What APIs does Ringly use for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I recently came upon [ringly.com](http://www.ringly.com), a product that lets you visually see notifications from your iPhone to a ring that you wear.  As far as I know, Apple does not expose any APIs that would alert your app when a text message arrives on your phone or the phone receives a call.

So how does Ringly work?  Does it require a jailbroken phone?  If those APIs are available, please point me to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Apple's [Notification Center Service (ANCS) Specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> The purpose of the Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS) is to give Bluetooth accessories (that connect to iOS devices through a Bluetooth low-energy link) a simple and convenient way to access many kinds of notifications that are generated on iOS devices.

This is publicly available and doesn't require a jailbroken phone.